# Joined inheritance without discriminator column

Tags: jpa, inheritance

I these legacy tables (in an Oracle database):

```
CREATE TABLE "SPL_OWN"."SL_DOCUMENTO" ( 
    "ID_DOCUMENTO"     NUMBER(20,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, -- Primary Key
    ...
    "ID_PARECER_GERAL" NUMBER(20,0), -- Foreign Key
    "ID_PROPOSITURA"   NUMBER(20,0), -- Foreign Key
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE "SPL_OWN"."SL_PARECER_GERAL" ( 
    "SL_PARECER_GERAL" NUMBER(20,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, -- Primary Key
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE "SPL_OWN"."SL_PROPOSITURA" (   
    "ID_PROPOSITURA"   NUMBER(20,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, -- Primary Key
    ...
);
```

The particularity here, is that SL_PARECER_GERAL.SL_PARECER_GERAL and SL_PROPOSITURA.ID_PROPOSITURA values are in fact equals to SL_DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO. Actually, SL_PARECER_GERAL and SL_PROPOSITURA can be considered as SL_DOCUMENTO subclasses (there is other tables in this situation, I am using these two as examples). In an Ideal situation, I should use an [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html) of type [JOINED](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/InheritanceType.html#JOINED). However, there is no [discriminator column](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html).

To determinate if a SL_DOCUMENTO is a SL_PROPOSITURA, SL_DOCUMENTO.ID_PROPOSITURA should be filled, while SL_DOCUMENTO.ID_PARECER_GERAL should be `NULL`. On the other hand if the SL_DOCUMENTO.ID_PARECER_GERAL is filled and SL_DOCUMENTO.ID_PROPOSITURA is `NULL`, SL_DOCUMENTO is a SL_PARECER_GERAL.

In my mapping, I am using no inheritance strategy.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_DOCUMENTO")
public class DocumentoORM {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENTO", sequenceName = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENTO")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_SL_DOCUMENTO")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "documento", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PARECER_GERAL", updatable = false)
    private ParecerGeralORM parecerGeral;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "documento", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROPOSITURA", updatable = false)
    private ProposituraORM propositura;

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseORM extends AbstractORM {

    @Id
    private Long id;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_PROPOSITURA")
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID_PROPOSITURA")) })
public class ProposituraORM extends BaseORM {

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROPOSITURA", nullable = false)
    private DocumentoORM documento;

    public ProposituraORM() {
    }

    public ProposituraORM(DocumentoORM documento) {
        super();
        this.documento = documento;
        this.documento.setPropositura(this);
    }

    // Getter & Setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SL_PROCESSO")
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID_PROCESSO")) })
public class ProcessoORM extends BaseORM {

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROCESSO")
    private DocumentoORM documento;

    public ProcessoORM() {
    }

    public ProcessoORM(DocumentoORM documento) {
        this.setDocumento(documento);
        documento.setProcesso(this);
    }

    // Getter & Setters

}
```

When ProposituraORM is inserted, the JPA makes that DocumentoORM be persisted before the ProposituraORM instance. However, although SL_PROPOSITURA.ID_PROPOSITURA has the same value as SL_DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO, the column SL_DOCUMENTO.ID_PROPOSITURA remains `NULL`. To correct this, I should create a workaround where I fill it "manually", towards native SQL. Obviously, the same machanism works for ProcessoORM.

Therefore I would like to know if there is a better alternative to use Joined inheritance without discriminator column. In some places I found references to the [@SecondaryTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html) and [@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html) annotations. Here, in StackOverflow I saw some related questions, but I was not able to apply them to my situation.

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: Why were you not able to use `@SecondaryTable`? It seems like a good fit for your situation. That way you would have both the `ProposituraORM` and the `ProcessoORM` classes with a `@SecondaryTable` defined. You could then make `DocumentoORM` embeddable and embed it into both classes.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear : Do you know any concrete example? May be not using Inheritance annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're almost there.

The `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance type would probably do it. In other words your `BaseORM` class should have

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class BaseORM extends AbstractORM {
```

You wouldn't even need to use the `@SecondaryTable` as the `DocumentoORM` is already associated with the `@OneToOne`.

To make sure all the ids are filled out correctly, you need to define the references on **both** sides of the association. So, in other words, if you have two objects `documento` and `propositura` then before you save you need to do the following:

```
documento.setPropositura(propositura);
propositura.setDocumento(documento);
```